# Movimentar personagem até ponto em Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity3d

Estou com um problema, preciso que meu personagem se mova uma determinada distância quando eu clico no botão, até aí eu consigo fazer.

O problema é que quando faço, ele não "anda" até o ponto, ele meio que se "teleporta", e não é essa a intenção. Preciso que ele percorra automaticamente esta distância.

Alguém pode me ajudar?

using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class movimento : MonoBehaviour {

```
public float posicao = 2f;
private bool clickBaixo;
private bool clickCima;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

    clickBaixo = moveDown.getBaixo();
    clickCima = moveUp.getCima();

    if(Input.GetKeyDown("up") || clickCima == true){
        transform.Translate(0,posicao,0);
    }

    if(Input.GetKeyDown("down") || clickBaixo == true){
        transform.Translate(0,(posicao)*-1,0);
    }
}
```

}

Atualizado:

using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class movimento : MonoBehaviour {

```
public float posicao = 2f;
public float vel = 10f;
private bool clickBaixo;
private bool clickCima;
private float novaPosicao;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

    clickBaixo = moveDown.getBaixo();
    clickCima = moveUp.getCima();

    if(Input.GetKeyDown("up") || clickCima == true){
        StartCoroutine("moveCima");
    }

    if(Input.GetKeyDown("down") || clickBaixo == true){
        StartCoroutine("moveBaixo");
    }
}

IEnumerator moveCima(){
    novaPosicao = transform.position.y + posicao;
    while(transform.position.y<novaPosicao){
        transform.Translate(0, vel*Time.deltaTime, 0);
        yield return null;
    }
}

IEnumerator moveBaixo(){
    novaPosicao = transform.position.y + posicao;
    while(transform.position.y<novaPosicao){
        transform.Translate(0, (vel*Time.deltaTime)*-1, 0);
        yield return null;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Você poderia editar a pergunta para postar nela a parte relevante do seu código? Afinal de contas não dá para saber o que é que não está funcionando sem vê-lo.

Comment: Como o colega @VictorStafusa menciona, o seu código é importante para que alguém possa apontar o seu erro. Provavelmente você está alterando o `transform.position` dele para a posição de destino (final), e por isso ocorre o "teleporte". Se for o caso, você deve usar uma alternativa como (1) usar física e aplicar uma força na direção do destino; (2) apontar o objeto do personagem para a direção do destino e transladar gradualmente segundo uma velocidade estipulada naquela direção *a cada quadro* (chamada de `update`); (3) usar [`Lerp`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Lerp.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você precisa saber qual efeito que você quer quando for andar com teu personagem pois existem diversas soluções. E todas dependem daquilo que você quer fazer. As mais fáceis são.

A primeira é usar uma força, você aplica uma força no rigidybody e o Unity se encarrega de mudar a posição para você.
https://youtu.be/PmA0paVG16g

A segunda é você somar pequenos passos atualizando a posição para chegar de um ponto ao outro. Não use while dentro de um Update, procure usar uma Coroutine.
Neste aqui eu uso o `MoveTowards`
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uTFfna91u4g

A terceira é usar o `Lerp`, assim como o MoveToward, lembre-se de usar uma variação de tempo para amenizar a transição
https://youtu.be/uGoAqv-uy6E?t=11m25s

Há tembém de tomar o cuidado em onde você coloca teus loopings e o que você coloca onde. Pois há uma grande diferença nas chamadas do `Update` e do `FixedUpdate`.
https://youtu.be/0rD4OuPxsuk

Comment: tentei andar aos, poucos com um while mas ficou com um lag gigante, se vc poder me dar um exemplo deste caso, colocar forca no rigidybody não tentei, vou tentar quando puder.

Obrigado pelas respostas.

Comment: Fique longe do while para fazer estas coisas se não estiver usando uma Coroutine. Vou editar a resposta, mas novamente, para ser mais direto preciso saber o efeito que está buscando no teu personagem.

Comment: muito obrigado, vou tentar essas maneiras, depois digo o que consegui...

Comment: Muito obrigado nils, consegui fazer com uma courotine, nunca tinha usado a courotine antes, eu comecei a programar games a 1 mes no maximo.

segue codigo atualizado na pergunta.

Comment: Caramba, mandou bem para que começou a fazer agora. Poucas pessoas que conheço optam por essa solução justamente por ser mais avançado. Parabéns!

Comment: sou programador web, tenho conhecimento de programação, mas não em games, rs.